# is it possible using spring to inject all interface implementations to a container automatically?

Tags: spring

is it possible using **spring** to inject all interface implementations to a container automatically?

I want to write something like:

```
List<SomeInterface> list;
```

and spring will automatically inject my implementations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is very simple.
As long as all your implementations are annotated with `@Service` or `@Component` or any other annotation that lets spring know that this is a **Bean** and you implement the same interface in all beans. 
All you have to do is annotate the collection field with `@Resource`

for example:

```
@Resource
private List<SomeInterface> list;
```

and all the implementations will automatically be inserted to this list.